# PHP and pagebreak in tinyMCE WYSIWYG

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm using PHP and tinyMCE WYSIWYG editor,and i have this text example :

```
 Text 1
  <!-- pagebreak -->
  Text 2 
 <!-- pagebreak --> 
 Text 3
```

How can i get just `text 2` ?

Comment: So i want to show just a part of post, then this comment  `<!-- pagebreak -->` help me to detect the desired text position. so my question is how to get this text position with PHP. i think to `strpos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split() function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php. Example:

```
$pieces=split("<!-- pagebreak -->", $text);
echo $pieces[1];
```

Is not the best solution. Other way is to use regular expressions http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Awesome :) 
just a little warning `Message: Function split() is deprecated`. 
Than i replace `split` with `explode` and it's work fine